# How do I add a policy statement to a customer managed policy through CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've created a customer-managed policy `Field-Bookish-Dev` via the AWS console with the following policy statement:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'd like to add an additional policy statement, that allows writing to a bucket, through CDK, so I devised the following:

- Get the policy up on AWS by its ARN using [`fromManagedPolicyArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.ManagedPolicy.html#static-fromwbrmanagedwbrpolicywbrarnscope-id-managedpolicyarn).
- Create a new policy statement that allows for writing to the bucket.
- Attach this new policy statement to the retrieved policy.

The following is the code directly related to the above tasks in TypeScript, and using `aws-cdk@2.85.0`:

```js
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as s3 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3";
import * as iam from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";

export class FieldBookBucketStack extends cdk.Stack {
   constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {  
     const s3Bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, ...);

     // Get customer-managed policy from its ARN.
     const fieldBookBucketPolicyArn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:policy/Field-Bookish-Dev";
     const fieldBookBucketPolicy = iam.ManagedPolicy.fromManagedPolicyArn(
       this,
      `field-book-bucket-policy-dev`,
       tcuBucketPolicyArn,
     ) as iam.ManagedPolicy;

     // Declare a new policy statement.
     const s3PutObjectPolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
       effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
       actions: ["s3:PutObject"],
       resources: [s3bucket.bucketArn],
       principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
     });

     // Add additional permission to existing policy.
     tcuBucketPolicy.addStatements(s3PutObjectPolicy);


     // Additional CDK setup unrelated to policies.
  }
}
```

When I try to deploy the stack I get the following error:

```
TypeError: fieldBookBucketPolicy.addStatements is not a function
```

**NOTE:** I could probably add the policy statement via the AWS console and call it a day, but I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do is feasible via CDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  A CDK app cannot modify resources, such as your Managed Policy, that it doesn't manage.  The `fromManagedPolicyArn` method returns an [IManagedPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.IManagedPolicy.html) construct. It is a [read-only reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external), useful for passing your existing Managed Policy's ARN to another construct. The `addStatements` method does not exist on `IManagedPolicy`, because that would mean changing an external resource, which the CDK can't do.

This is a common CDK pattern. Methods like `fromFooName` return a read-only `IFoo` [interface class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces), not a writeable `Foo` construct.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know! It's most likely mentioned in the docs but I missed it.